# How can I remove space between body and top of page

Tags: html, css, spacing

I have been working with CSS and HTML to create basically a banner and navbar. I've been trying to get it to stick to the very top, but after I saw it in chrome, I noticed both the body tag and the HTML tag are detatched. I've tried removing all the margins and padding from every single part that could be responsible for the space, but I couldn't get rid of it. What is a good way to do this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="demo.html">Demo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

 nav
{
  text-align: left;
}

nav ul
{
  list-style: none;
  /*margin: 0 10; corrected*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a
{
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Screenshot (as requested):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please add `nav ul { margin: 0; }`.

Comment: can we have a screenshot of the problem highlighted as the question is not that clear

Comment: use reset css http://www.cssreset.com/ which will not allow elements to take default styles given by browsers

Comment: @emmanuel Thanks! That fixed it. It seems that is was because it said margin: 0 10; w/o the units (10px). Would you happen to know why?

Comment: `margin: 0 10;` is invalid CSS; measurements must have units.  since the `10` is invalid and there's no such thing as a "partially" valid property, the whole line is ignored.

Comment: Sorry, it seems the space is still there... I can't seem to find where it comes from. Also, @emmanuel, I read it and it shouldn't really affect it if all margins are zero right? Thanks for the help

Comment: Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eb414gbs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 years later - I just solved a similar problem - I had extra spaces.
Try removing the blank spades before your first  (it's indented with spaces or a tab in the code)

Answer (score 5):

I tried every solution here and nothing really worked, mainly because I don't have navigation in my simple page or a header.

What worked for me was using the universal selector like this:

```
*, html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

4 years later, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem just now and i resolved with

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code snippet

```
body{
    margin: 0%;   
}
```

for more information please refer to the given website:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the space using below code

```
nav ul {
list-style: outside none none;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the space is still there. It's at the top of the body element, but the body element is not at the top of the html element.